Why does ECS binpack strategy on memory always scale up a new EC2 instance despite available resources?
I'm using ECS with an Auto Scaling group as a capacity provider to deploy tasks on EC2 (t3.micro, 2 vCPU, 1 GB memory). I've set the task placement strategy to binpack based on memory. However, I've noticed that ECS always scales up a new EC2 instance to deploy a new task, even if an existing instance has enough CPU and memory available. Consequently, there is only one task per EC2 instance. I expect that all tasks should be placed on a single EC2 instance if it has sufficient memory.
Here are some actions I've already checked:

Port conflict: The network mode is set to awsvpc in the ECS task definition, so each task gets its own ENI, which prevents port conflicts.
EC2 storage: Each EC2 instance has a storage size of 30GB (EBS GP3). My container is a nginx-based web app with 1 MB of static files, so the storage is more than sufficient for running multiple containers.

The following configurations might be related to this issue,
Capacity provider configurations
capacity provider: autoscaling group
base: 0
weight: 100
target capacity: 100%
managed instance draining: true
managed instance scaling: true
scale in protection: false

ECS service configurations
desired count: 1
placement strategy:
  type: binpack
  field: memory
scheduling strategy: REPLICA
service connect:
  enabled: true
  namespace: my_namespace
  services:
    - port name: web
      discovery name: hello
      client aliases:
        - port: 80
          dns name: hello
  

ECS task definition
network mode: awsvpc
CPU: 256
Memory: 128
container definitions:
  - name: web
    image: nginx
    port mappings:
      - name: web
        container port: 80
        protocol: tcp

Any insights or suggestions?
Additional information 
I changed the instance type from t3.micro to t3.small (2 vCPUs, 2 GB memory) and deployed 4 ECS tasks. The ECS cluster autoscaled up 2 EC2 instances, placing 2 tasks on each instance.

I've identified the root cause of the issue: the maximum number of Elastic Network Interfaces (ENIs) allowed per EC2 instance. Each ECS task, when using the awsvpc network mode, requires one ENI on the EC2 instance. This can lead to exceeding the ENI limit for the instance type in use. The maximum number of network interfaces that you can use varies by instance type. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ec2/latest/instancetypes/gp.html#gp_network)
The possible solutions to me are

Use bridge network mode
Turn on the awsvpctrunking account setting: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-instance-eni.html

